# Renaming a text file with the hostname on Solaris OS

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, operating-system, solaris

I am executing the below command wherein I would like to have the output file generated with the hostname of the machine on which the command is been executed.

uname -i 1>>output.text

E.g: if I execute the above command on the host 'ABC' then the text file should be created as 'ABC.text' instead of 'output.text'

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
$ uname -i > `hostname`.text
```

Or if you really intended to have the output appended as in your original question, then it would be:

```
$ uname -i >> `hostname`.text
```

Note that I am using the more portable Bourne Shell syntax above where in enclosing a `command` in back-ticks is equivalent to $(command) on more modern shells.